# Fisher's information for multiple binomials

Tags: maximum-likelihood, fisher-information

I am trying to quantify error of the MLE for the following model using Fisher's information:
$Y_{j} \sim Binomial(n_{j}, p_{j})$
$logit(p_{j}) = \eta + \gamma_{j}$
where the $n_{j}$'s and $\gamma_{j}$'s are known.

Looking at some old notes from my statistics class, I see that Fisher's information for a single observation $x$ with parameter $\theta$ is equal to the negative of
[image: Fisher's information]

In my case, I have calculated both
$\frac{d^{2}}{d\eta^{2}}\log f(\textbf{y}|\eta)$
$f(\textbf{y}|\eta)$
but I am unsure how to deal with the integral because each observation is multivariate with a $y_{j}$ from each binomial. Do I have to use multiple integrals with respect to each $y_{j}$?

Comment: Oh wait, each $y_{j}$ is discrete, so would Fisher's information just be the expected value of $-\frac{d^{2}}{d\eta^{2}}\log f(\textbf{y}|\eta)f(\textbf{y}|\eta)$ over all possible combinations of $y_{j}$?

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind, I think I figured it out:

$I(\eta) = E_{\eta} (\frac{d^{2}}{d\eta^{2}}\log f(\textbf{Y}|\eta)) = \sum_{j = 1}^{L} n_{j}logit(\eta + \gamma_{j})$
where L is the number of binomals there are.